# Sockets Programming with Video Streaming with python

Tags: python, sockets, websocket, rdp

I have to make a project where i accept multiple client connections and I have to send screenshots of the screen of the client to the server and show it on the screen and if I have to be able to stream clients screen to the server. How do I go about this? I've been trying to make this for about 2 months now. I am stuck and don't know how to make it.
Any reply is greatly appreciated.
This is the server code I have so far.

```
import threading
import socket
from queue import Queue

NUMBER_OF_THREADS = 2
JOB_NUMBER = [1,2]
queue = Queue()

class MultiServer(object):
    #Initialize Server Object with host, port, socket, all connections and all the IP addresses
    def __init__(self):
        self.host = ""
        self.port = 8965
        self.socket = None
        self.all_connections = []
        self.all_addresses = []
        self.all_users = []
    #Create Socket
    def socket_create(self):
        #If socket creation fails except the error and show to the User and exit the program
        try:
            self.socket = socket.socket()
        except socket.error as msg:
            print("Socket creation failed, error: " +str(msg))
            sys.exit(1)
        #Use socket.setsockopt to keep reusing the same port    
        self.socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        return
    def socket_bind(self):
        #Bind socket to port and wait for incoming connections
        try:
            self.socket.bind((self.host, self.port))
            self.socket.listen(5)
            #Is binding the socket fails show error to the user and try again in 5 seconds
        except socket.error as msg:
            print("Socket binding error: " + str(msg))
            time.sleep(5)
            self.socket_bind()
        return

    def accept_connections(self):
        #Accept Connections from multiple clients and save to list
        #Close all old connections to prevent errors
        for c in self.all_connections:
            c.close()
        self.all_connections = []
        self.all_addresses = []

        while True:
            try:
                conn, address = self.socket.accept()
                conn.setblocking(1)
                client_hostname = conn.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
                address= address + (client_hostname,)
            except Exception as ex:
                print('Error accepting connections: %s' %str(ex))
                # Inifinite Loop
                continue
            self.all_connections.append(conn)
            self.all_addresses.append(address)
            print('\nConnection has been estalished: {0} ({1})'.format(address[-1], address[0]))
        return
    def send_commands(self):
        while  True:
            cmd = input("$:")
            if cmd == "list":
                self.list_connections()
    def list_connections(self):
        """ List all connections """
        results = ''
        for i, conn in enumerate(self.all_connections):
            try:
                conn.send(str.encode(' '))
                conn.recv(20480)
            except:
                del self.all_connections[i]
                del self.all_addresses[i]
                continue
            results += str(i) + '   ' + str(self.all_addresses[i][0]) + '   ' + str(
                self.all_addresses[i][1]) + '   ' + str(self.all_addresses[i][2]) + '\n'
        print('----- Clients -----' + '\n' + results)
        return

def create_workers():
    server = MultiServer()
    for i in range(2):
        t = threading.Thread(target=work, args=(server,))
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
def work(server):
    while True:
        x = queue.get()
        if x == 1:
            server.socket_create()
            server.socket_bind()
            server.accept_connections()
        if x == 2:
            server.send_commands()
        queue.task_done()
        return
def create_jobs():
    for x in JOB_NUMBER:
        queue.put(x)
    queue.join()
def main():
    create_workers()
    create_jobs()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And this is the Client code I have so far

```
import socket
class Client(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.serverHost = '127.0.0.1'
        self.serverPort = 8965
        self.socket = None

    def socket_create(self):
        """ Create a socket """
        try:
            self.socket = socket.socket()
        except socket.error as e:
            print("Socket creation error" + str(e))
            return
        return

    def socket_connect(self):
        """ Connect to a remote socket """
        try:
            self.socket.connect((self.serverHost, self.serverPort))
        except socket.error as e:
            print("Socket connection error: " + str(e))
            time.sleep(5)
            raise
        try:
            self.socket.send(str.encode(socket.gethostname()))
        except socket.error as e:
            print("Cannot send hostname to server: " + str(e))
            raise
        return

    def recieve_requests(self):
        """ Controle of de server nog actief is """
        try:
            self.socket.recv(10)
        except Exception as ex:
            print("Couldn't recieve Commands: " + str(ex))
            return
        while True:
            data = self.socket.recv(20480).decode("utf-8")
            print(data)
        print("mislukt")





client = Client()
client.socket_create()
def main():
    client = Client()
    client.socket_create()
    try:
        client.socket_connect()
    except Exception as ex:
        print(f"Socket connection error: {ex}")
    while True:
        try:
            client.recieve_requests()
        except Exception as ex:
            print(ex)
```

Comment: This question is way too broad. This is a complex project and it is unclear what you have so far and where exactly you are stuck.

Comment: Just dumping some code into the question does not say what problem you have exactly, i.e. where you are stuck.

Comment: I don't know how to send video and screenshots through sockets. I don't know how to implement it in my code. I know you have to use a buffer but I don't understand what they are and how to use it.

Comment: Video and screenshots are just data like any other data, i.e. like files etc. There is nothing special for this when sending over a socket. Of course you somehow need to get the data in the first place but that does not seem to be the focus of your question. Note that there are also [many similar questions](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+python+send+screenshot+socket).